# Customize acronyms to set description as italic

Tags: glossaries

I am using glossaries package and the `\newacronym` command for a document, I want the description to be printed as italic text the first time it appears, but I dont want to do this in every definition of the acronym, is there a way to modify an internal hook or set some style that makes the long description automatically set to italic

Comment: Do you want the abbreviation in italic as well on first use or just the long form? If just the long form, see, for example, [Mixed Glossary (Emphasis) Sample](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/mixed-glossary-emph.shtml)

Comment: yes, that's the idea, I am trying to make it work

Answer (score 5):

With just the base `glossaries` package, you can use something like [this example from the glossaries gallery](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/mixed-glossary-emph.shtml):

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,acronymlists={main}]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makeglossaries

\newacronymstyle{long-short-emph}%
{%
  \ifglshaslong{\glslabel}%
  {% acronym
   % This is an adaptation of \glsgenacfmt
    \ifdefempty\glscustomtext
    {%
      \ifglsused\glslabel
      {%
        \glsifplural
        {%
          \glscapscase
          {%
            \acronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}}\glsinsert
          }%
          {%
            \acronymfont{\Glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}}\glsinsert
          }%
          {%
            \mfirstucMakeUppercase
              {\acronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}}\glsinsert}%
          }%
        }%
        {%
          \glscapscase
          {%
            \acronymfont{\glsentryshort{\glslabel}}\glsinsert
          }%
          {%
            \acronymfont{\Glsentryshort{\glslabel}}\glsinsert
          }%
          {%
            \mfirstucMakeUppercase
              {\acronymfont{\glsentryshort{\glslabel}}\glsinsert}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
      {%
        \glsifplural
        {%
          \glscapscase
          {%
            \emph{\glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}\glsinsert}\space
            (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}})%
          }%
          {%
            \emph{\Glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}{\glsinsert}}\space
            (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}})%
          }%
          {%
            \mfirstucMakeUppercase
              {\emph{\glsentrylongpl{\glslabel}{\glsinsert}}\space
               (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshortpl{\glslabel}})}%
          }%
        }%
        {%
          \glscapscase
          {%
            \emph{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}\glsinsert}\space
            (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{\glslabel}})%
          }%
          {%
            \emph{\Glsentrylong{\glslabel}\glsinsert}\space
            (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{\glslabel}})%
          }%
          {%
            \mfirstucMakeUppercase
             {\emph{\glsentrylong{\glslabel}\glsinsert}\space
             (\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{\glslabel}})}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
    {%
      \glscustomtext
    }%
  }%
  {% regular term
    \ifglsused{\glslabel}{\glsgenentryfmt}{\emph{\glsgenentryfmt}}%
  }%
}%
{%
  \GlsUseAcrStyleDefs{long-short}%
}

\setacronymstyle{long-short-emph}

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-acronym}

\begin{document}

\section{First Use}

Regular entries: \gls{ac}, \gls{accumsan}, \gls{amet},
\gls{bibendum}, \gls{consectetuer}, \gls{diam}.

Acronyms: \gls{aeu}, \gls{afm}, \gls{anp}, \gls{cas},
\gls{cdg}, \gls{cea}, \gls{dia}.

\section{Next Use}

Regular entries: \gls{ac}, \gls{accumsan}, \gls{amet},
\gls{bibendum}, \gls{consectetuer}, \gls{diam}.

Acronyms: \gls{aeu}, \gls{afm}, \gls{anp}, \gls{cas},
\gls{cdg}, \gls{cea}, \gls{dia}.

Full form: \acrfull{aeu}.

\printglossary[style=mcolindex]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Alternatively, you can use the extension package [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra). This uses a different mechanism for abbreviations, which are defined using `\newabbreviation` (same syntax as `\newacronym`). The abbreviation styles are set using `\setabbreviationstyle[`*category*`]{`*style-name*`}`. To allow for easy conversion, `\newacronym` is redefined in terms of `\newabbreviation` with `category=acronym`, which means the style needs to be set with `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{`*style-name*`}`. The `long-short` abbreviation style uses `\glsfirstlongdefaultfont` for the long-form font on first use. This makes for a much simpler document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glsfirstlongdefaultfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}

\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-acronym}

\begin{document}

\section{First Use}

Regular entries: \gls{ac}, \gls{accumsan}, \gls{amet},
\gls{bibendum}, \gls{consectetuer}, \gls{diam}.

Acronyms: \gls{aeu}, \gls{afm}, \gls{anp}, \gls{cas},
\gls{cdg}, \gls{cea}, \gls{dia}.

\section{Next Use}

Regular entries: \gls{ac}, \gls{accumsan}, \gls{amet},
\gls{bibendum}, \gls{consectetuer}, \gls{diam}.

Acronyms: \gls{aeu}, \gls{afm}, \gls{anp}, \gls{cas},
\gls{cdg}, \gls{cea}, \gls{dia}.

Full form: \glsxtrfull{aeu}.

\printglossary[style=mcolindex]

\end{document}
```

This produces a similar result, except for the explicit full form at the end, which in this case also has the long form in italics.

[image: image of document]

Note that with `\setabbreviationstyle` you need to use `\glsxtrfull` not `\acrfull`. Similarly `\glsxtrshort` instead of `\acrshort` and `\glsxtrlong` instead of `\acrlong`. The `\acr...` commands are designed for use with the base `glossaries` acronym mechanism and don't allow for the `glossaries-extra` style settings.

Comment: If you use `\acrfull{aeu}` for a first use, it does not italicize the long form. Is it possible to change this behavior, or should I use `\glsreset{aeu} \gls{aeu}` instead? I am talking about your second example using `glossaries-extra`.

Comment: @fidekild Sorry, I'll correct that. Don't use `\acrfull` with `glossaries-extra`. Use `\glsxtrfull` instead.

Answer (score 1):

from [The users guide](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) (page 110)

> \glstextformat{< text >}

For example, to make all link text appear in a sans-serif font, do:

```
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
```

In your case you could use `\glstextformat` to define all linked text to be italics. Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries} 

\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{support vector machine}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}
    blah balh blah \gls{svm} some more text and then \gls{svm}

    \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I saw the result but this turns all the text to italic even the second `\gls{svm}` short version and I need to change just the long description the first time it appears